# How to organize webdriver and chimp tests

Tags: meteor, mocha.js, webdriver-io, chimp.js

I have a lot of acceptance test suites using chimp, webdriver, and mocha for my meteor project. I need them to run in a specific order, as some are dependent on others. I was able to do this in a shell script, that calls

```
chimp --mocha --path=/path_to_first_test \
path_to_second_test \
path_to_third_test
```

I am wondering if there's a better way to do this? Does anyone know if either webdriver or chimp have a tool that does this, or if there is another tool that works with them that I could use? I wasn't able to find any.

Answer (score 0):

You should never have tests that depend on each other. You need to build your test suite in such a way that each test can run independent.

If you need to jump to a certain part of your journey, then build in the code that allows you to do that using fixtures and test-specific code.

If you insist however, then you can pass in chimp individual feature files on the command line and it should run them in sequence